# HTTP request inside Azure CLI GitHub action fails with SSL expired error

Tags: github-actions, azure-cli

We are using the AZ CLI GitHub Action `azure/CLI` (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-cli-action)

The script that this workflow calls makes an HTTP request to an external API. This cURL call fails with the following:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

However I can confirm that the same request works locally.

The problem workflow step looks like this:

```
- name: Run script
  uses: azure/CLI@1.0.4
  with:
    azcliversion: 2.0.72
    inlineScript: |
      $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/github/scripts/script.sh
```

Why does cURL think that the SSL cert for the external API domain is expired, when I can make the same call to the same API domain successfully on my own machine?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was that the `azcliversion` points to a version of the AZ CLI that has outdated certificates.

The problem was solved by removing the `azcliversion` field altogether, as the default version is *latest*, as specified in the docs for the action:

> `azcliversion` – **Optional** Example: 2.0.72, Default: latest

So the step now looks like this:

```
- name: Run script
  uses: azure/CLI@1.0.4
  with:
    inlineScript: |
      $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/github/scripts/script.sh
```

Probably related to this: https://twitter.com/letsencrypt/status/1443621997288767491

> Our cross-signed DST Root CA X3 expired today. If you are hitting an error, check out fixes in our community forum. We're seeing higher than normal renewals, so you may experience a slowdown in getting your certificates.